# Dynamic Bootstrap Tabs In Laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I have two tables , categories and articles.Each category has id and name. Each articles has id, name and category id. Now I want to load the data on each tab when a user click on specific category_id.so related product will be shown on each category tab. I have tried but couldn't get the solution.

Category Model

```
 public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Article Model

```
 public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Controller

```
 public function index(){
        $categories = Category::with('articles')->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();
        return view('welcome',compact( 'categories'));
    }
```

Here is the view :

```
             <nav>
                <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link " id="nav-home-tab-{{$category->id}}" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home-{{$category->id}}" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">{{$category->title}}</a>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </nav>

            @foreach($categories as $category)

                <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                         <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home-{{$category->id}}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab-{{$category->id}}">
                             <div class="row clearfix">
                                 @foreach($category->articles as $article)
                                  <div class="col-md-3">
                                     <div class="box mt-2 mb-2">
                                         <img src="{{ $article->images ['thumb'] }}">

                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                                 @endforeach
                             </div>
                         </div>
                </div>
           @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav>
   <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      @foreach($categories as $count => $category)
      <a  id="nav-home-tab-{{$category->id}}" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home-{{$category->id}}" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true"
      @if($count == 0) class="nav-item nav-link active" @else()class="nav-item nav-link "@endif>{{$category->title}}</a>
      @endforeach
   </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
   @foreach($categories as $count => $category)
   <div @if($count == 0) class="tab-pane fade show active" @else class="tab-pane fade" @endif id="nav-home-{{$category->id}}"
   role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab-{{$category->id}}">
   <div class="row ">
      @foreach($category->articles as $article)
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="box mt-2 mb-2">
            <img src="{{ $article->images ['thumb'] }}">
            <h2>قالب بوتسراپ شرکتی</h2>
            <p>قالب بوت استراپ شرکتی کاملا فارسی سازی شده و رایگان میتوانید دانلود کنید</p>
            <div class=" download-btn">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mb-1"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> دانلود قالب </a>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark mb-1 float-left"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> دموی قالب </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      @endforeach
   </div>
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
```